# PHP Like System / 'Most Liked' (Need for logic)

Tags: php, mysql

I'am trying create a basic comment system, I was success but I have a problem right now.

I can't list "most liked" comments and I don't have an idea about how can I.

My **votes database** showing like that:

```
voteid  | value     | entryid   | userid
25      | like      | 257       | 17
24      | like      | 257       | 17
23      | unlike    | 257       | 18
```

I create a new like with this code:

```
    $vote = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO votes (entryid, userid, value) VALUES (:entryid, :userid, :value)");
    $vote->bindParam(':entryid', $entryid);
    $vote->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
    $vote->bindParam(':value', $value);
    $vote->execute();
```

And my question.

***What's my need SQL Query***?

I've tried like this:

```
  $bestliked = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM votes");
  $best = $bestliked->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP|PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 2);
```

But I can't list the array which have most subarray. It only seems that;

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 8
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
        [3] => 4
        [4] => 5
        [5] => 6
        [6] => 7
        [7] => 9
        [8] => 10
        [9] => 11
        [10] => 12
        [11] => 13
        [12] => 14
        [13] => 15
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 16
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 17
    )
```

Thanks All!

Comment: this should get you started `SELECT COUNT(voteid) AS likes, entryid WHERE value = 'like' GROUP BY entryid`

Comment: @cmorrissey This code only lacks of sorting but I add "ORDER BY likes DESC" .
It's work perfectly right now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to sum the group count and sort it descending:

```
  Select *,count(*) as sum group by entryid where value='like' order by sum desc
```